# Integration of Two Manipulatable Cylinders

Tags: numerical-integration, manipulate, graphics3d

### Introduction

I created the following code to simulate the many possible interactions between a cylindrical protein crystal and a x-ray beam during serial femtosecond crystallography.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    {
     { EdgeForm[None], Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.4], Specularity[White, 20]], 
       GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[{{-h + x, y, z}, {h + x, y, z}}, 1*10^-6], 
       RotationTransform[α Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}].RotationTransform[β Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}]]},
     { EdgeForm[None], Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 20]], 
       Cylinder[{{-1*10^-5, 0, 0}, {1*10^-5, 0, 0}}, r]} },

    Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"} ],

  {{α, 0}, -1, 1}, {{β, 1}, -1, 1}, 
  {{r, 1*10^-7}, 1*10^-7, 6*10^-6} , 
  {{h, 5*10^-6}, 1*10^-6, 10*10^-6},
  {{x, 0}, -1*10^-5, 1*10^-5},
  {{y, 0}, -1*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, 
  {{z, 0}, -1*10^-5, 1*10^-5} ]
```

### Problem

I would like to be able to display the volume of the intersection of the two objects. As far as I have looked, this doesn't seem to be possible using only `Cylinder` and `Graphics3D`. If there is a way to find this volume using only `Graphics` objects that someone knows of, please enlighten me.

Also, the use of `RegionPlot3D` and `NIntegrate` as demonstrated by this example looks promising.

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
NIntegrate[Boole[x^2 + y^2 < 1 ], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

But my problem with using these functions is I don't know how to apply the `Manipulate` function to these raw inequalities in order to get the geometric transforms, variable height, translation, and change in beam radius like I have in my `Graphics3D` model.

Really all I care about it that it is manipulatable like the `Graphics3D` model I have shown and that the volume of the intersection is displayed as the model is manipulated. I greatly appreciate any help on this.

### Solution

```
cyl[{x_, y_, z_}, r_, h_] := y^2 + z^2 < r^2 && -h < x < h
xform[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_] := RotationTransform[a Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}].RotationTransform[b Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}].TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}]

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   {EdgeForm[None], Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.4], Specularity[White, 20]],
   GeometricTransformation[ Cylinder[{{-h, 0, 0}, {h, 0, 0}}, 1*10^-6], xform[x, y, z, a, b]]},
   {EdgeForm[None], Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 20]], Cylinder[{{-1*10^-5, 0, 0}, {1*10^-5, 0, 0}}, r]}
 },
PlotLabel -> Chop[10^21 NIntegrate[
  Boole[cyl[{x0, y0, z0}, r, 1*10^-5] && 
    cyl[InverseFunction[xform[x, y, z, a, b]][{x0, y0, z0}], 
     1*10^-6, h]], {x0, -2*10^-5, 2*10^-5}, {y0, -2*10^-5, 
   2*10^-5}, {z0, -2*10^-5, 2*10^-5},
  Method -> {"MultidimensionalRule", "Generators" -> 9}, 
  MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 4], AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 2]],
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}],
 {{a, 0}, -1, 1},
 {{b, 1}, -1, 1},
 {{r, 1*10^-7}, 1*10^-7, 6*10^-6} ,
 {{h, 5*10^-6}, 1*10^-6, 10*10^-6},
 {{x, 0}, -1*10^-5, 1*10^-5},
 {{y, 0}, -1*10^-5, 1*10^-5},
 {{z, 0}, -1*10^-5, 1*10^-5}
]
```

Comment: What you have is a maths problem, unrelated (in its current state) to Mathematica. You need to find out how to calculate the volume of the intersection of two cylinders. Off topic here, I think.

Comment: Well, @MichaelE2's answer shows that my comment above was unfair

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to get *Mathematica* to calculate the equation of a transformed cylinder, which can then be used to calculate the volume.

First, since you're translating the cylinder, too, I rewrote your transformation to include the translation.  We can also define inequalities to define the cylinder.

```
xform[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_] := 
 RotationTransform[a Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}] . RotationTransform[b Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}] . 
   TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}]; 
cyl[{x_, y_, z_}, r_, h_] := y^2 + z^2 < r^2 && -h < x < h;
```

While `xform` can be used to transform the `Cylinder`, the inverse `InverseFunction[xform[x, y, z, α, β]]` can be used to transform the equation of the cylinder.

In the `Manipulate`, you can find and display the volume of the intersection of the cylinders with

```
PlotLabel -> 
 Chop[10^21 NIntegrate[
    Boole[cyl[{x0, y0, z0}, r, 1*10^-5] && 
          cyl[InverseFunction[xform[x, y, z, α, β]][{x0, y0, z0}], 1*10^-6, h]],
    {x0, -h, h}, {y0, -r, r}, {z0, -r, r}, 
    Method -> {"MultidimensionalRule", "Generators" -> 9},
    MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 4],
    AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3]]
```

The `Chop[10^21 ...]` is unnecessary, but I found it convenient.  The value of the integral is quite small and `NIntegrate` returns a much smaller imaginary part that is only numerical error.  One could use something like `Chop[NIntegrate[..], 10^=30]` instead.  Without it, the label is too long to display nicely.

The options

```
MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[2, 4], AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3
```

are included because sometimes the integral is slow to converge.  You can probably refine these or other `NIntegrate` options to suit your needs.

*Update notes:*
When `NIntegrate` takes more than 5 seconds, the results are unpredictable, including messages that seem to be the result of being interrupted and not an inherent problem with the integral or the code.  Alterations that improved speed:

1. Restricted integration domain to box bounding laser beam cylinder.
2. Added `Method -> {"MultidimensionalRule", "Generators" -> 9}`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael E2! This looks great. However, I am running into an error when I try to manipulate the rotational variables a and b in the model. NIntegrate::inumri: "The integrand Boole[y0^2+z0^2<1/100000000000000&&-(1/100000)<x0<1/100000&&1.\ (0. +Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])^2+1.\ (0. +Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])^2<1/1000000000000&&-(1/200000)<1.\ (0. +0.140901\ x0-0.31332\ y0-0.939137\ z0)<1/200000] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1},{0,1},{0,1}}. " Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added the code I am using to implement your solution above

Comment: You could try changing the domain of integration to depend on the radius `r` of the blue cyl. (to limit `y` and `z`) and `h` of the yellow (to limit `x`). See update.  You might have to delve into the extensive `NIntegrate` documentation to come up with a really good solution.  I run into time constraints of `Manipulate` (calculations should take less than 5 sec.).

Comment: @Zer0 Specified `Method` -- seems to help adequately.  See update.